Triggering EOF From Keyboard Input (Terminal)
I'm a new[er] programmer and going through K&R's "ANSI C" 2nd edition book.  The example has the following program that counts characters using getchar() until EOF is reached.
include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double nc;

    for (nc = 0; getchar() !=EOF; ++nc)
        ;
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}

After compiling and running (using Notepad and Terminal), I can input "123456789", hit enter (nothing happens), then input Ctrl+Z, then hit enter again, and the program terminates with a result of 10 (reasonable outcome, but I'm unsure if it counted the 10th character as the Ctrl, the "Z", the "Ctrl+Z", or the Enter key... I suspect it's the Enter key).  If I try inputting "123456789CtrlZ" + "Enter", nothing happens.  If my only input is "Ctrl+Z" then "Enter", the program terminates with a result of 0 (expected).
I am also running this program in CLion, but I cannot satisfy EOF and I have to manually abort the program and therefore I never get a character count (I've tried Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+D, Enter, ESC, combinations of all, etc.)
This topic is somewhat covered here, which helps, but doesn't quite satisfy my question. I know I don't need to know the actual value of EOF (which prints as "-1").  This is more of a practical question about how this program executes. I assume the for loop doesn't execute until I hit "Enter" after inputting a string of characters, but:

Why doesn't "123456789CtrlZ" + "Enter" result in a main() fully executing with an output of 9?

Appreciate any wisdom on this.  I'm trying not to move forward in the book unless I fully understand each example.
Edit with data to support the answer below:


Why are you using a 35 year old book if you are a new programmer? Do you also plan to program on a 35 year old computer?

It's not counting the Ctrl-Z or the following newline at all. All it counts is the first line (the nine digits and the newline for that).

Also, why are you using a floating-point value for integer numbers?

@Lundin C hasn't changed much.  I want to learn C first (specifically memory management) so I better understand how my C++ works.  I'm not sure how the age of the book matters.

@Someprogrammerdude This code is straight from K&R, aka "lets do really strange things just for the heck of it"

Maybe a silly question, but in "123456789CtrlZ" in the question, did you actually type “CtrlZ”, or press Ctrl and Z? This other question suggests that Ctrl+Z without a preceding newline should still work on Windows. (As for CLion, open question.)

@Someprogrammerdude I'd have to ask Kernighan and Ritchie.  It's their example in their book.

@Xejo C has changed a lot, with 3 major updates (C90, C99, C23) and 3 minor ones (C95, C11, C17) since the time when the book was published in the pre-standard dark ages. Also the book even struggled to accurately cover the version of C that was live back in 1989.

@Ry- Good question.  No, I typed "123456789", then  Ctrl+"Z", then enter.  I did not type out the letters "C, t, r, l"...

@Lundin Am I experiencing the program's behavior because it's a 35 year old book, or because of some other reason?

If you want to learn C++, then please learn C++, not the totally different language C. Especially a very old version of C that have very little in common with modern C++. A character-counting program in C++ would look very different.

@Ry- Ctrl-Z must be first on a line, so if you've entered some text, it has to be text<newline><ctrl-z><newline>.

@Someprogrammerdude I respect your opinion, but I've received the advice on many occasions that learning C is worthwhile endeavor for foundational understanding.  But this is way off topic from my question above.

@Xejo I see no problem in the code. There is an unrelated problem - the code invokes undefined behavior on the intended target for K&R 2nd edition where main() must return 0;, since the OS will use the result code. It shouldn't have been a surprise to K&R that some people who try to run their code on for example Unix, where it may crash. There's a lie in the preface "This Second Edition of The C Programming Language describes C as defined by the ANSI standard". ANSI X3.159-1989 and other drafts requires a function to return a value in case that value is used by the caller.

@Xejo All of that historical nonsense and shortcomings of K&R is of no concern in modern C though, where it is fine to write int main() {} without a return statement.

The problem with learning C first is that you then must unlearn quite a lot to learn C++ properly. Like the habit to use standard C++ containers instead of writing your own, to use the C++ string class instead of arrays and pointers, to use the C++ vector container instead of arrays, to avoid pointers almost completely in C++, all of the object-oriented stuff, the large amount of functionality in the C++ standard library which is a very large superset of the C library. And there are also differences in the languages themselves... Code that might be valid C might not be valid C++.

I recommend you go the other way: Once you have intermediate knowledge of C++, learn C if you need and want to.

@Someprogrammerdude I offer you my unofficial +1 for your persistence and confidence.  However, I expect to find tremendous value through my imminent suffering learning raw pointers/memory allocation, and anything else C++ abstracts away.  This is my hobby, I'm not looking for a job.  I have the time, passion, and patience for foundational understanding.  Awesome, complex programs programmed with ease will come later - but "suffering" comes first.  I can't be talked off this ledge - I believe my mentors when they say the best C++ programmers were experts in C first.  So, here I go. :)


Why doesn't "123456789CtrlZ" + "Enter" result in a main() fully executing with an output of 9?

Because Ctrl-Z anywhere but first on a line places its regular value in the input buffer (and then skips the rest of the line until you press Return). Ctrl-Z has value 26 in the Windows world and the special case EOF has value -1.
However, when you press Ctrl-Z first on a line, it places EOF in the input buffer. Since input is line buffered, you'll then have to press Return to get the EOF. A session could then look like this:
hello world<Return>
this is fun<Return>
<Ctrl-Z><Return>

Output:
24

The first two Return keystrokes in the example will be counted.

This all appears to be true in my follow-on testing.  I'll edit my question to include the testing inputs/outputs for future readers.  In response to @JonGreen's answer below, it "appears" that Ctrl-Z is in fact ignored when not placed at the beginning (meaning, it's not being counted and its not terminating).  So it may be useful to clarify how its being used if its not ignored?

@Xejo Glad it helped! It's not being ignored and you can print the values that you get from getchar() to verify example. When you press Ctrl-Z after having entered other characters, you will actually read a Ctrl-Z (which will be counted) but the rest of the characters on the same line will be skipped (including the return).

I'm not sure this is the behavior I'm seeing.  Look at the 4th row of the table I posted in the OP.  The output of that line is 11, which [I assume] counts 1-9, the space, and the Enter key.  If Ctrl-Z were counted, wouldn't I see an output of 12?  If you're right, it would have counted the Ctrl-Z but not the first Enter key.  Thoughts?

@Xejo Yes it's the behaviour I described that you're seeing. It counts 1-9, the space, and the Ctrl-Z. Use the program I linked to so that you see what it is that it's counting.

The EOF character (CTRL-Z in Windows; CTRL-D in Linux and Unix) only works when it's the first character on a line. If you've already typed something, it's ignored. This is why it has no effect when you've already typed "123456789" on a line.
Your tenth counted character, by the way, is the newline character (\n), not the EOF character. If in doubt - exercise for the student! - read the incoming characters into a buffer instead of throwing them away, and do a hex dump of each line when you receive a newline or EOF. (Hint: beware buffer overflow!)
I will echo what others have commented, by the way. If you want to learn C, you should move onto a modern version (C17 or C23) as soon as you've learnt the rudiments from K&R.

Nitpick regarding "it's ignored" - It is not.

Why do you need a buffer? Each incoming can be printed in hex whether or not the input is buffered.
